# Ruby string manipulation of numbers

Tags: ruby, string

I have example this number: 5032

I want to get this: 5.0.32

How can I do this with ruby string manipulation?

Comment: Because I cant save a number like 5.3.2 in my database (MySQL)

Comment: if those numbers ever roll over, ie, 10.0.0,  this solution will break.   Does it have to be stored as a number?  Why not a char(20)? or three number columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be curious to hear the pros and cons of these different solutions. What's the fastest ? What's the clearest ? Are regular expressions expensive ?

Here's yet another solution:

```
sprintf("%s.%s.%s%s", *5032.to_s.split(""))
```

Here's our results. Mine is slowest:

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 500000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { n.times {"5032".sub(/^(.)(.)/,"\\1.\\2.")}}
  x.report { n.times {"5032".insert(2, ".").insert(1, ".")}}
  x.report { n.times {sprintf("%s.%s.%s%s", *5032.to_s.split("")) }}
end



     user     system      total        real
  0.610000   0.000000   0.610000 (  0.607663)
  0.320000   0.000000   0.320000 (  0.325050)
  3.030000   0.000000   3.030000 (  3.029342)
```

Comment: +1 for benchmarking. And notice that you have to go up to around 1e5 to get non-instantaneous results for any of them; the speed difference is hardly worth worrying about.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little bit vague but you can do this:

```
number = "5032"
number = "5032".insert(2, ".").insert(1, ".")
puts number
```

See the API doc for insert [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/insert).

Comment: Which one of the 2 methods is fastest ?

Comment: I think this should be faster because it's not using regexps. But what do you exactly want to achieve? Is the number you have to convert always 4 digits? If not what's the rule for placement of separators, etc.?

Comment: @Behrang, Since you are manipulating data that you'll then store in a database, it's likely that the speed of this particular manipulation does not matter: It will be dwarfed by the time it takes to insert the data into the database.  Pick the clearest code: optimize for your time, not the machine's.

Comment: @Wayne: I %100 agree. I was just answering the OP's question.

Comment: @Behrang, Please accept my apology for misdirecting my comment to you.  I read too quickly, and not well enough.  I intended the comment for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

```
> 5032.to_s.sub(/^(.)(.)/,"\\1.\\2.")
=> "5.0.32"
```

Comment: Which one of the 2 methods is fastest ?

Comment: @Rails, how many times do you want to loop or run it? if you need to run several tens or hundred of thousands, regexes are tends to be slow generally. note: `/...../` are regexes.